# Another problem with msdb110_upgrade.sql and COLLATE

Tags: sql-server

I had a problem while updating our SQL Server 2017 to CU27.

After the update, SQL Server refused to start with the following error:

> Script level upgrade for database 'master' failed because upgrade step
> 'msdb110_upgrade.sql' encountered error.

The actual error is :

> Cannot resolve the collation conflict between "French_CI_AS" and
> "French_100_CI_AS" in the equal to operation.

So I restarted the server with -T902 flag and inspected the script in C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL14.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Install.

I found the missing collate statements and updated the script and saved it to the original place.
When I run it in SSMS it’s fine, but when I restart the server without the flag, I still have the same error.

My guess is that the script doesn’t run from this directory but from another place.

So does anyone know where this script is so I can modify it and restart with the -T902 flag.

Comment: If you search on "upgrade step 'msdb110_upgrade.sql' encountered error.' you will find many discussions with different issues and solutions. That should be your first step.

Comment: Hi SMor, I already searched. Once, someone had almost the same collation problem. It ended up by a full reinstall of the SQL Server. As I tried to explain, I know exactly what to do to solve the problem I just don't know where to put the solution and I don't want a full reinstall. Collation problems are really annoying in SQL Server.